# Mamzer from a rape

Tags: halacha, women, mamzer

During the pogroms a married Jewish woman is raped by a Cossack. Is the child born of this rape a Mamzer?

Does the intercourse of a married Jewish woman with a non-Jew have to be consensual for the child to be a Mamzer?

Comment: The unison of a non jew and a jew according to halacha doesn't make a mamzer, even if it was willingly.

Comment: The child would be considered a mamzer only if it could be proven he was the child of the rapist, and not of the woman's husband.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi what is your source for this? I believe it is incorrect (see my answer below)

Comment: Yevamot 45b: "And the halakha is that with regard to a gentile or slave who engaged in intercourse with a Jewish woman, the lineage of the offspring is unflawed, whether she was an unmarried or a married woman."

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi where in your quote do I see that "The child would be considered a mamzer only if it could be proven he was the child of the rapist, and not of the woman's husband." ?

Comment: I forgot where I read that, but it is obviously contradicted by this Gemara.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the definition of a *mamzer*, e.g., from [chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4007896/jewish/What-Is-a-Mamzer.htm)

> the Hebrew term mamzer [...] refers only to the **offspring of people whose relationship
> would be punishable with karet (excision)**. This includes many
> close-blood relatives or a woman who was concurrently married to
> someone other than the child’s father.

The Rambam lists these punishable relations in [chapter 1](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960647/jewish/Issurei-Biah-Chapter-One.htm) of Hilchot Issurei Biah. **They don't include relations with non-Jews.**

**As such the offspring of the rape of a Jewish woman by a non-Jew is not a *mamzer*.**

Even if the man was a Jew, the offspring would only be a *mamzer* if the man and woman were prohibited to marry each other (see [Hilchot Issurei Biah 15:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960663/jewish/Issurei-Biah-Chapter-Fifteen.htm))

Answer (score 0):

H. Issurei Biah 15:1

> איזה הוא "ממזר" (דברים כג,ג) האמור בתורה:  זה הבא מערווה מן
> העריות--חוץ מן הנידה, שהבן ממנה פגום ואינו ממזר; אבל הבא על שאר
> העריות--**בין באונס בין ברצון**, בין בזדון בין בשגגה--הוולד ממזר.
> ואחד זכרים ואחד נקבות, אסורין לעולם--שנאמר "גם דור עשירי, לא יבוא"
> (שם), כלומר לעולם
>
> What is meant by a "mamzer"? The term refers to a person conceived
> from a forbidden sexual relationship. A niddah is an exception. A son
> conceived from such relationships is blemished, but is not a mamzer.
> When, however, a person enters into any other forbidden sexual
> relationships, **whether through rape, or willingly,** whether
> deliberately or inadvertently, the offspring produced is a
> mamzer. Both males and females are forbidden forever, as it
> states: "even the tenth generation" (Deuteronomy 23:3) i.e., the
> prohibition is everlasting.

However H. Issurei Biah 15:3-4 elaborates that:

> גוי ועבד הבא על בת ישראל, **הוולד כשר--בין בפנויה בין באשת איש**, בין
> באונס בין ברצון… זה הכלל:  בן הבא מן העבד, או מן הגוי, או מן השפחה, או
> מן הגויה--הרי הוא כאימו, ואין משגיחין על האב
>
> When a gentile or a servant enter into relations with a Jewish woman,
> **the child is acceptable.** This applies whether the woman is unmarried or married, **whether she was raped or engaged in relations
> willingly**... This is the general principle: When a child is born
> from a servant, a gentile, a maid-servant, or a female gentile, he is
> like his mother. We are not concerned with the father.

SA EH 4:19 similarly records the halakhah as follows:

> עכו"ם ועבד שבאו על הממזרת הולד ממזר ואם באו על בת ישראל בין פנויה בין
> אשת איש הולד כשר ופגום לכהונה
>
> If a gentile or a slave cohabit with a female mamzer, the offspring is
> a mamzer. If they cohabit with a Jewish woman, whether she is single
> or married, the offspring is permitted [to marry into the
> congregation], but is considered damaged with regard to marrying a
> Kohen.

Comment: Does this apply to gentile men?

Comment: Shulchan Aruch Even Haezer simian 4 states the child is not a mamzer.  עכו"ם ועבד שבאו על הממזרת הולד ממזר ואם באו על בת ישראל בין פנויה בין אשת איש הולד כשר ופגום לכהונה:
If a non-Jew or a slave cohabit with a female mamzer, the offspring is a mamzer. If they cohabit with a Jewish woman, whether she is single or married, the offspring is permitted [to marry into the congregation], but is considered damaged with regard to marrying a kohen.

Comment: A relation with a non-Jew is not what the Rambam calls a forbidden relation, see chapter 1 of Issurei Biah

Comment: @Deuteronomy “Any extramarital union is prohibited”. This is true. But it is not correct that the child of a woman and another man is always a mamzer. This is only correct in very specific cases

Comment: @Chatzkel you are correct, and the halakhah is restated as such in the MT as well. Answer edited accordingly.

Comment: A suggestion - use the term 'Arayot' transcribed out in English, and define it, to prevent any misunderstandings e.g. what is 'forbidden relations.'  Because as your answer shows, mamzer is directly and solely dependent on Arayot.